# What does 七年之痒 mean?

Tags: translation, culture, idioms

I looked it up and something about the Seven Year Itch but I'm kind confused. Does it have any deep meaning in Chinese culture?

Comment: The etymology of this phrase is not Chinese, but comes from USA. Here's all the info you need: http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/seven-year-itch.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means seven years after marriage, both husband and wife would face numerous temptations that would harm their relationship. The seven years is a vague expression, sometimes a couple gets trouble earlier, sometimes later.

There is a [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0048605/) about this. [Wikipedia](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E4%B8%83%E5%B9%B4%E4%B9%8B%E7%97%92) has some hints too. [Its Baidu page](http://baike.baidu.com/view/1562.htm) tells that it's borrowed from foreign country.

---

### Case Study

There is a perfect case: [潘粵明 與 董潔](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%E6%BD%98%E7%B2%B5%E6%98%8E%20%E8%91%A3#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=aae465304e6319c6&hl=en&q=%E6%BD%98%E7%B2%B5%E6%98%8E%20%E8%91%A3%E6%BD%94%20%E4%B8%83%E5%B9%B4%E4%B9%8B%E9%A4%8A), matching the definition pretty well.